# Terraform lookup AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following code in my main.tf file:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
  region     = "us-east-1"
  alias      = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
  region     = "us-west-1"
  alias      = "us-west-1"
}

module "us-east_vpc" {
  source = "./setup-networking"

  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.us-east-1"
  }
}

module "us-west_vpc" {
  source = "./setup-networking"

  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.us-west-1"
  }
}
```

And then in my modules file I have:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "region"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
  provider             = "aws.region"
  cidr_block           = "${lookup(var.vpc_cidr, ${aws.region.region})}"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags {
    Name = "AWS VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "default" {
  provider = "aws.region"
  vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "default" {
  provider = "aws.region"
  vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

  cidr_block        = "${lookup(var.subnet_cidr, ${aws.region.region})}"
  availability_zone = "aws.region"

  tags {
    Name = "AWS Subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "default" {
  provider = "aws.region"
  vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.default.id}"
  }

  tags {
    Name = "Main Gateway"
  }
}
```

As you can see in the modules file code I am trying to do a lookup to find the VPC CIDR mask and the subnet CIDR mask from map variables.

The trouble is that I can't seem to sort out how to get the region to be used as a lookup value.

If I hard code these values:

```
cidr_block = "10.10.0.0/16"
cidr_block = "10.10.10.0/24"
```

The script works as expected but I don't want to hard code the values.

Can someone with more Terraform experience help me understand how I can properly reference the region to lookup the correct value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the region that's currently in use by the provider by using the [`aws_region` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/region.html).

So in your case you could do something like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "region"
}

data "aws_region" "current" {
  provider = "aws.region"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
  provider             = "aws.region"
  cidr_block           = "${lookup(var.vpc_cidr, ${data.aws_region.current.name})}"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags {
    Name = "AWS VPC"
  }
}

...
```

Comment: The above code didn't exactly work but it did leave me to the solution - so thank you! I'm going to mark this as the answer but put the code I used in another answer.

Comment: The example code was a minimal example of how to use it, it obviously needs expanding to cover your other resources or to get at availability zones but that wasn't included in your question.

Comment: Understood - and that's why I marked your answer as accepted. :) But I just wanted to provide a working example for anyone else that might stumble upon this post. Thanks again for all your help! I was really stumped.

Comment: Upvoted you. Thanks for the tip. Just a quick question. What is the purpose of the alias snippet?
alias = "region"

The docs say this, but it would help, if there is an example:
alias optional, string

Alias for using the same provider with different configurations for different resources, e.g. eu-west

Comment: It's just following what was in the question. I wouldn't personally do that and would rely on the default unaliased provider in this specific case.

Answer (score 44):

I was looking for the same answer for a different problem. I wanted to get the region for a name of a role, I was able to get the info by doing this:

1.- Create a file like `data.tf` and add this info:

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}
```

2.- Get the info from the data by calling this variable in any TF file:

```
name = "${var.vpc-name}-${data.aws_region.current.name}-Bastion-Role"
```

This way it will get the region where you are executing the code, and you don't have to mess with the `provider.tf` file.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
provider "aws" {
    alias = "region"
}

data "aws_region" "current" {
    provider = "aws.region"
}

data "aws_availability_zone" "current" {
    provider = "aws.region"
    name = "${data.aws_region.current.name}a"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
    provider = "aws.region"
    cidr_block = "${lookup(var.vpc_cidr, data.aws_availability_zone.current.name)}"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    tags {
            Name = "${data.aws_region.current.name} Security VPC1"
            Region = "${data.aws_region.current.name}"
            Account = "Security"
    }
}
```