# How to get default GCP project and region with Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

The standard terraform boilerplate for Google Compute Engine (GCE/GCP) is:

```
provider "google" {}
```

How can I get my default `project` and `region` with that? I need something analogous to `aws_region` in AWS (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619602/terraform-lookup-aws-region)).

In some cases these are specified externally in the environment variables:

```bash
export GOOGLE_PROJECT=myproject
export GOOGLE_REGION=europe-west2
terraform apply
```

Less often they are explicitly visible in hcl code:

```
provider "google" {
  project = "myproject"
  region  = "europe-west2"
}
```

How to proceed when neither is the case?

Answer (score 10):

### Basic

Use the [google_client_config](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/client_config.html) data source:

```
data "google_client_config" "this" {}

output "region" {
  value = data.google_client_config.this.region
}

output "project" {
  value = data.google_client_config.this.project
}
```

### Mutliple providers

This can be used even with multiple providers:

```
provider "google" {
  region = "europe-west2"
}

provider "google" {
  alias  = "another" // alias marks this as an alternate provider
  region = "us-east1"
}

data "google_client_config" "this" {
  provider = google
}

data "google_client_config" "that" {
  provider = google.another
}

output "regions" {
  value = [data.google_client_config.this.region, data.google_client_config.that.region]
}
```

Output:

```
$ terraform init
$ terraform apply --auto-approve

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

regions = [
  "europe-west2",
  "us-east1",
]
```

Comment: This does have the downside of persisting the access token in tfstate.